# Click button (python), having problems with both mechanize and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, mechanize

I'm trying to click the "Coevolution Scores (TXT)" button that pops up after clicking the "Export..." button, however, using a python script [here](http://polyview.cchmc.org/cgi-bin/coevolve.cgi?JOB=c8a266e0d7ba7cc), I could not do it either with mechanize nor selenium, using different selection types.

Is there any other way, or can you possibly figure out what I am doing wrong?

I used this code:

```
url="http://polyview.cchmc.org/cgi-bin/coevolve.cgi?JOB=c8a266e0d7ba7cc"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/ProgramFiles/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@title='Export...']").click()
```

also tried by link_text and by putting `find_element_by_link_text`, instead of putting the argument inside. Below is the button I try to click.

```
    <form id="downloadMat" target="formTarget" method="POST" action="coeviz_data.pl">
            <input name="x" class="idData" type="hidden" value="683436.chi">
            <input name="dl" class="dlData" type="hidden" value="683436.chi.wph">
            <input name="w" class="weighted" type="hidden" value="wph">
            <input name="res" type="hidden" value="scores.txt">
            <button onclick="submit()">Coevolution Scores (TXT)</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Forgot to say, the most common error is "element not found"

Comment: Please add a code sample of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML here as well??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying to select is inside an `<iframe>` element. This means that you have to switch frame first before selecting anything that is inside it. This will work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
url="http://polyview.cchmc.org/cgi-bin/coevolve.cgi?JOB=c8a266e0d7ba7cc"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/ProgramFiles/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
driver.switch_to_frame('ifCoeViz')
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@title='Export...']").click()
```

Comment: Best way to use `CSS_SELECTOR` here instead to locate `Export` button as `button[title='Export...']` for better performance. Thanks

Comment: @Preto if I helped you please consider accepting the answer (Green tick at the left of this answer)

Comment: sorry, did not know how it worked, I'll keep it in mind :)